# "Cannot Increment endIndex" because of emoji

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have a function that finds the current word a user has selected in a UITextView. However, if I call this function when an emoji is in the UITextView.text property,  I see a crash. I believe this is because of the different character counts in String vs NSString.

How do I properly convert this?

```
func currentWord() -> String {

    let cursorPosition = selectedRange.location
    let separationCharacters = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: " ")

    // crash occurs here
    let beginRange = Range(text.startIndex.advancedBy(0) ..< text.startIndex.advancedBy(cursorPosition))
    let endRange = Range(text.startIndex.advancedBy(cursorPosition) ..< text.startIndex.advancedBy(text.characters.count))

    let beginPhrase = text.substringWithRange(beginRange)
    let endPhrase = text.substringWithRange(endRange)

    let beginWords = beginPhrase.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separationCharacters)
    let endWords = endPhrase.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(separationCharacters)

    return beginWords.last! + endWords.first!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this is because of the different character counts in String vs NSString

You're right about that. You are shifting back and forth between using NSRange (Cocoa) and Range (Swift) — and they work differently. And NSString (Cocoa) and String (Swift) have different ideas of where the character boundaries are. You need to be consistent.

Once you've used `selectedRange` in the first line, you are in the Cocoa world of NSRange. You need to stay consistently in the Cocoa world. Don't use any Swift Ranges! Don't use any Swift `characters`!

Form your `beginRange` entirely using NSRange — for example, call `NSMakeRange`. Don't use `characters.count`; stay in the NSString world and use the string's `length` (in Swift, that is its `utf16.count`). Then all will be well.

Comment: I tried this but now it says the Range is out of bounds when I call "substringWithRange" method. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, My error was that the NSMakeRange should be (start, end - start). I had (start, end).